# How can I get metadata of file and assign it to variables?

Tags: shell, applescript, zsh, automator

I have a pdf file.
I want to get that file's (filename, size, pages, author, subject) metadata tags and assign it to different variables into automator app. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Are you using zsh or applescript? Only tag the appropriate language.

Answer (score 1):

The bash command `mdls '/path/to/file.pdf'` should return all of the metadata for a pdf file. if you run this in a `run shell script` action, it will produce a list of all metadata that can be processed by a subsequent action.

Alternately, you can ask for specific metadata keys like so:

```
mdls -name kMDItemFSName -name kMDItemNumberOfPages '/path/to/file.pdf'
```

Assigning these to different variables is a bit tedious, but not too difficult.